# How do you say "actively developing" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my resume I talked about some projects that I have worked on like: "Created a" "Developed a program" "Designed a program" and in all of my high-tech interviews (like Microsoft) they asked "and you abandoned it?" with a laugh

How can I make it clear that I am still developing and working on the program and advancing them in short and professional way?

Comment: What's wrong with "actively developing" or a variation? Such as, "Created and now actively developing program X".

Comment: "Created and now actively developing" doesn't sound professional to me, can I say it in shorter way? Plus is it true to say "actively developing"? I mean I already developed it once but now inserting more code to support new features @KillingTime

Comment: Have you, at any stage, mentioned implementation or commercial release, and ongoing support and maintenance?

Comment: The project is *[still] [**under** development*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22project+is+under+development%22)